# Receiving arguments from Windows Context menu

Tags: c#, windows, contextmenu, regedit

I have done this before but for the life of me can't remember how to do this...

In my explorer context menu I added a new entry (go to regedit...go to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT...bla bla bla)... Now when I click on my option I want to pass in the file path, file name, those kind of things to my application...and then use it there?

Answer (score 6):

The default value of the .ext\shell\open\command key should contain the path to your .exe with the "%1" argument.  Explorer substitutes that with the full path to the file.  Which you can read in your .exe through the Main() method argument or Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().

Comment: what if the application is already running and you want to add some selected files to an existing list?

Answer (score 0):

Try this projects links:
[How to fetch the value on the click of Context Menu Item and pass the same as a parameter to the executable](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0397ed6f-ce8f-4bfa-9934-3246d374c128/how-to-fetch-the-value-on-the-click-of-context-menu-item-and-pass-the-same-as-a-parameter-to-the?forum=csharpgeneral) ,
[.NET Shell Extensions - Shell Context Menus](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/512956/NET-Shell-Extensions-Shell-Context-Menus)

or this one this url: codeproject.com/Articles/3111/C-NET-Command-Line-Arguments-Parser

---

code exemple:

```
    // Variables
    private StringDictionary Parameters;

    // Constructor
    public Arguments(string[] Args)
    {
        Parameters = new StringDictionary();
        Regex Spliter = new Regex(@"^-{1,2}|^/|=|:",
            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase|RegexOptions.Compiled);

        Regex Remover = new Regex(@"^['""]?(.*?)['""]?$",
            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase|RegexOptions.Compiled);

        string Parameter = null;
        string[] Parts;

        // Valid parameters forms:
        // {-,/,--}param{ ,=,:}((",')value(",'))
        // Examples: 
        // -param1 value1 --param2 /param3:"Test-:-work" 
        //   /param4=happy -param5 '--=nice=--'
        foreach(string Txt in Args)
        {
            // Look for new parameters (-,/ or --) and a
            // possible enclosed value (=,:)
            Parts = Spliter.Split(Txt,3);

            switch(Parts.Length){
            // Found a value (for the last parameter 
            // found (space separator))
            case 1:
                if(Parameter != null)
                {
                    if(!Parameters.ContainsKey(Parameter)) 
                    {
                        Parts[0] = 
                            Remover.Replace(Parts[0], "$1");

                        Parameters.Add(Parameter, Parts[0]);
                    }
                    Parameter=null;
                }
                // else Error: no parameter waiting for a value (skipped)
                break;

            // Found just a parameter
            case 2:
                // The last parameter is still waiting. 
                // With no value, set it to true.
                if(Parameter!=null)
                {
                    if(!Parameters.ContainsKey(Parameter)) 
                        Parameters.Add(Parameter, "true");
                }
                Parameter=Parts[1];
                break;

            // Parameter with enclosed value
            case 3:
                // The last parameter is still waiting. 
                // With no value, set it to true.
                if(Parameter != null)
                {
                    if(!Parameters.ContainsKey(Parameter)) 
                        Parameters.Add(Parameter, "true");
                }

                Parameter = Parts[1];

                // Remove possible enclosing characters (",')
                if(!Parameters.ContainsKey(Parameter))
                {
                    Parts[2] = Remover.Replace(Parts[2], "$1");
                    Parameters.Add(Parameter, Parts[2]);
                }

                Parameter=null;
                break;
            }
        }
        // In case a parameter is still waiting
        if(Parameter != null)
        {
            if(!Parameters.ContainsKey(Parameter)) 
                Parameters.Add(Parameter, "true");
        }
    }

    // Retrieve a parameter value if it exists 
    // (overriding C# indexer property)
    public string this [string Param]
    {
        get
        {
            return(Parameters[Param]);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -2):

You should open a window from the context menu and get your data there to pass to your application.